# How do I scrape a particular data from URL

Tags: go, web-scraping

I have a URL https://stake.com/sports/home?iid=sport%3A139012669&modal=bet

If you open the baove URL in browser the you can see the contents. I am interested in a particular field called

**Odds**
128,058.44

Now I have tried to write a golang application to fetch the URL data and then I am thinking to apply some transformation on the resultant data to get my desired field "Odds", but it seems that I am not gettinmg any response as I am being blocked by cloudflare.

But when i manulayy open the uRL in any browser then it works. How can I make work in golang ?? any idea??

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://stake.com/sports/home?iid=sport%3A138921503&modal=bet"

    // Make GET request
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error making GET request:", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Read response body
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading response body:", err)
        return
    }

    // Print the response body
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

I am expecting the odds to be stored uisng golang API.

Comment: You have to make the _exact_ same request(s) that your browser makes, including all headers, all cookies, etc. pp.

Comment: @Volker can you please help me frame a curl request for the same.. I am not able to do it as it is rendered under react modal which comes after the population of DOM.

Comment: I'd recommend using a package like github.com/go-rod/rod or github.com/chromedp/chromedp to make the requests from a real headless browser.